# How to make Visual Studio 2010 publish like 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2010, publish

I recently converted a project to Visual Studio 2010 and now I can't figure out how to get it to publish like I did in 2008. In 2008 I started a publish and told it the folder I wanted all the files dropped into. Then I zipped them myself and copied them to the server. Is that not possible in VS2010?

I tried "Build deployment Package" but that created a zip file with all my code buried down about 20 folders. Far from convenient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just right click on the website root in the Solution Explorer (highlighted in my partial screenshot), and choose "Publish Web Site" from the context menu.

[image: Right-click website]

[image: Choose Publish]

This will bring up the Publish dialog, where you can specify the drop location.

[image]

***Edit based on comments below***

If this is a Web Applicaiton Project, it's slightly different, but still possible.  You still right click and choose"Publish" BUT change the "Publish Method" to "File System"

[image: Publish WAP]

Comment: My project isn't a website. I think it's a "C# Web Application". When I go to publish on my web project it brings up the one-click publish dialogue which I don't want.

Comment: Ahhh. Hang on.  We can do that, too.  Let me check how we do it.

Comment: @William - There you go.  Updated the answer with even more pics.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! Exactly what I was looking for! You sir are a gentleman.